# UITabBarController not using NavigationController

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, xamarin.ios, tabbar

I'm using MonoTouch and my application setup looks something like this,

NavController
   -TabBarController
      -NavController
          -View1

This works then I click on a tab and am directed to View1. The problem is that this was performed by the tabBarController and not the navigationController. So I get no Back button. Is there a way to capture a TabItemClicked event and manually use the NavigationController to push the View1 onto the stack? So I can get a back button.

I'm hiding the TabBar once I get to View1, so at the moment, there is no way back from View1.

Comment: You find some info about Combining UIViewController interfaces in this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CombiningViewControllers/CombiningViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH104-SW1). I'm not sure but it's not a good way to include a TabBarController inside a NavigationController.

Comment: Why are you nesting a TabBarController inside a nav controller? [iOS documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CombiningViewControllers/CombiningViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH104-SW1) says that a nav controller should not incorporate a tab bar controller. I hope you have good reason for not going with the recommendation. Having said that, putting nav controller inside a tab bar controller is alright.

Comment: I started with a nav controllers inside the TabBarController, but couldn't see how to pop back up to the home view once I had a navigated somewhere. (I hide the tabbar so I need some sort of back button with logic.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it may help you
http://21gingerman.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/tutorial-and-sample-code-for-iphone-app-with-tab-bar-and-nav-bar/